# How to have a column in CSV Helper accepts comma(,) in c#

Tags: c#

I have upgraded my csv helper into its latest version. My csv file does have an option not to quote all fields.

example :
Name, Age, Location
Juan Delacruz, 20, city,state,zip

but the generated csv file will become like this :

```
----------------------------------------------
Name          | Age | Location |       |     |
----------------------------------------------
Juan Delacruz | 20  | city     | state | zip |
----------------------------------------------
```

it adds another column for state and zip.

i want my result to be like this :

```
----------------------------------------
Name          | Age | Location         |
----------------------------------------
Juan Delacruz | 20  | city, state, zip |
----------------------------------------
```

and here is my CsvConfiguration

```
var csvConfig = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            {
                Delimiter = , ,
                ShouldQuote = field => false,
            };
```

Do you have any idea how to do it?

Comment: One potential way is to change the object that you're passing into CsvHelper. That object might contain a single string property that has the Location formatted the way you want it. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: yes , I formatted the value of the Location into string property
Location = "city,state,zip"

Comment: Okay - and did that give you the desired output?

Comment: Still no. The same problem occurs. @mason

Comment: Please edit that code into the question, in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: Are you saving to a csv file or reading from an existing csv that you did not produce?

Comment: Is it possible to enter sample data?

Comment: @insane_developer i am saving to a csv file

Comment: @meysamasadi , this is my sample data. I have an object name  ColumnDefinition that looks like this : 
```public class ColumnDefinition
{
    public string Name {set;get;}
    public int Age {set;get;}
    public string Location {set;get;}
}```

 ```Name = "Juan" , Age = 20, Location = "city,state,zip" ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find the desired output with the following code. No need to change any settings.

```
public static string StationDetailsCallStringToCSV()
{
    var csv = new StringBuilder();
    ColumnDefinition cd = new ColumnDefinition()
    {
       Name = "Juan",
       Age = 20,
       Location = "city,state,zip"
     };
     using (var parser = new ChoCSVWriter<ColumnDefinition>(new StringWriter(csv)).WithFirstLineHeader().UseNestedKeyFormat(true).ThrowAndStopOnMissingField(false))
     {
         parser.Write(cd);
     }
     Console.WriteLine(csv.ToString());
     return csv.ToString();
}
```

output:

[image]